# TESR and Custom Java Models (1.12.2)

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

First post here.
Well I'm having a little problem to TESR and Java Models;
So, In first of all, I'm not newer to Java and also to programming, but i dont have too much experience with forge.

I was wondering to rescale a cube from this model according to a value provided by the TileEntity.

I have already tried creating variables into model and change it externally, but failed. Untill this, model was rendering in the world, in the correct place and etc.

Now i tried add the rescaling values to my model constructor, and now model doesnt even render in world.

```java
//Model Class
package com.gpginc.gp_extended.blocks.renderer.models;

//Made with Blockbench
//Paste this code into your mod.

import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelBase;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelBox;
import net.minecraft.client.model.ModelRenderer;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;

public class ModelFluidContainer extends ModelBase {
    private final ModelRenderer bone;
    private final ModelRenderer glasses_left;
    private final ModelRenderer glasses_right;
    private final ModelRenderer lava;
    private final ModelRenderer water;

    /**
     * I've tried changing this values, and they were placed where u found water_y and lava_y, respectively
     */
    public int waterY = 0;
    public int lavaY = 0;

    public ModelFluidContainer(int water_y, int lava_y) {
        textureWidth = 128;
        textureHeight = 128;

        bone = new ModelRenderer(this);
        bone.setRotationPoint(0.0F, 24.0F, 0.0F);
        bone.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(bone, 56, 0, -8.0F, -1.0F, -8.0F, 16, 1, 16, 0.0F, false));
        bone.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(bone, 0, 28, -2.0F, -15.0F, -8.0F, 4, 14, 16, 0.0F, false));
        bone.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(bone, 0, 49, -8.0F, -16.0F, -8.0F, 16, 1, 1, 0.0F, false));
        bone.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(bone, 0, 55, -8.0F, -16.0F, 7.0F, 16, 1, 1, 0.0F, false));
        bone.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(bone, 1, 35, -2.0F, -16.0F, -7.0F, 4, 1, 14, 0.0F, false));
        bone.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(bone, 4, 40, 7.0F, -16.0F, -7.0F, 1, 1, 14, 0.0F, false));
        bone.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(bone, 4, 41, -8.0F, -16.0F, -7.0F, 1, 1, 14, 0.0F, false));

        glasses_left = new ModelRenderer(this);
        glasses_left.setRotationPoint(0.0F, 24.0F, 0.0F);
        glasses_left.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(glasses_left, 0, 0, 7.0F, -15.0F, -7.0F, 0, 14, 14, 0.0F, false));
        glasses_left.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(glasses_left, 9, 0, 2.0F, -15.0F, -7.0F, 5, 14, 0, 0.0F, false));
        glasses_left.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(glasses_left, 9, 0, 2.0F, -15.0F, 7.0F, 5, 14, 0, 0.0F, false));

        glasses_right = new ModelRenderer(this);
        glasses_right.setRotationPoint(0.0F, 24.0F, 0.0F);
        setRotationAngle(glasses_right, 0.0F, 3.1416F, 0.0F);
        glasses_right.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(glasses_right, 0, 0, 7.0F, -15.0F, -7.0F, 0, 14, 14, 0.0F, false));
        glasses_right.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(glasses_right, 9, 0, 2.0F, -15.0F, -7.0F, 5, 14, 0, 0.0F, false));
        glasses_right.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(glasses_right, 9, 0, 2.0F, -15.0F, 7.0F, 5, 14, 0, 0.0F, false));

        lava = new ModelRenderer(this);
        lava.setRotationPoint(0.0F, 24.0F, 0.0F);
        lava.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(lava, 88, 21, 2.0F, -1.0F, -6.7F, 4, lava_y, 13, 0.0F, false));

        water = new ModelRenderer(this);
        water.setRotationPoint(0.0F, 24.0F, 0.0F);
        water.cubeList.add(new ModelBox(water, 90, 80, -6.7F, -1.0F, -7.0F, 4, water_y, 13, 0.0F, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Entity entity, float f, float f1, float f2, float f3, float f4, float f5) {
        bone.render(f5);
        glasses_left.render(f5);
        glasses_right.render(f5);
        lava.render(f5);
        water.render(f5);
    }
    public void setRotationAngle(ModelRenderer modelRenderer, float x, float y, float z) {
        modelRenderer.rotateAngleX = x;
        modelRenderer.rotateAngleY = y;
        modelRenderer.rotateAngleZ = z;
    }
}
```

```java
//TESR class
package com.gpginc.gp_extended.blocks.renderer.tileentity;

import com.gpginc.gp_extended.blocks.machines.fluidcontainer.FluidContainerBlock;
import com.gpginc.gp_extended.blocks.machines.fluidcontainer.TileEntityFluidContainer;
import com.gpginc.gp_extended.blocks.renderer.models.ModelFluidContainer;
import com.gpginc.gp_extended.util.Reference;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.GlStateManager;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.tileentity.TileEntitySpecialRenderer;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.Side;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;

@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public class TileEntityFluidContainerRenderer extends TileEntitySpecialRenderer<TileEntityFluidContainer>
{
    private static final ResourceLocation TEXTURE_ALL = new ResourceLocation(Reference.MOD_ID + ":textures/blocks/special/fluid_block_container.png");

    public TileEntityFluidContainerRenderer() {}

    public void render(TileEntityFluidContainer te, double x, double y, double z, float partialTicks, int destroyStage, float alpha)
    {
        GlStateManager.enableDepth();
        GlStateManager.depthFunc(515);
        GlStateManager.depthMask(true);

        ModelFluidContainer newmodel = new ModelFluidContainer(Math.round(te.waterValue / 10), Math.round(te.lavaValue / 10));
        if (destroyStage >= 0)
        {
            this.bindTexture(DESTROY_STAGES[destroyStage]);
            GlStateManager.matrixMode(5890);
            GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
            GlStateManager.scale(4.0F, 4.0F, 1.0F);
            GlStateManager.translate(0.0625F, 0.0625F, 0.0625F);
            GlStateManager.matrixMode(5888);
        } else this.bindTexture(TEXTURE_ALL);

        GlStateManager.pushMatrix();
        GlStateManager.enableRescaleNormal();
        GlStateManager.translate((float)x, (float)y + 1.0F, (float)z + 1.0F);
        GlStateManager.scale(1.0F, -1.0F, -1.0F);
        GlStateManager.translate(0.5f,-0.5f,0.5f);

        newmodel.waterY = Math.round(te.waterValue / 10);
        newmodel.lavaY = Math.round(te.lavaValue / 10);

        newmodel.render(null, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.0625f);
        GlStateManager.disableRescaleNormal();
        GlStateManager.popMatrix();
        GlStateManager.color(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);

        if (destroyStage >= 0)
        {
            GlStateManager.matrixMode(5890);
            GlStateManager.popMatrix();
            GlStateManager.matrixMode(5888);
        }

    }
}
```

```java
//For some use, tileentity class
package com.gpginc.gp_extended.blocks.machines.fluidcontainer;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.gpginc.gp_extended.blocks.machines.fluidcontainer.container.ContainerFluidContainer;
import com.gpginc.gp_extended.util.Reference;

import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.InventoryPlayer;
import net.minecraft.init.Items;
import net.minecraft.inventory.Container;
import net.minecraft.inventory.ItemStackHelper;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemBucket;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntityLockableLoot;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.util.ITickable;
import net.minecraft.util.NonNullList;

public class TileEntityFluidContainer extends TileEntityLockableLoot implements ITickable
{

    private NonNullList<ItemStack> blockContents = NonNullList.<ItemStack>withSize(16, ItemStack.EMPTY);
    public int waterValue = 0;
    public int lavaValue = 0;


    private int currentWaterValue, currentLavaValue;

    private final int maxWater = 100;
    private final int maxLava = 100;

    private int numPlayersUsing, tickSinceSync;


    @Override
    public boolean hasFastRenderer() 
    {
        return true;
    }
    public void increaseWaterCount(EntityPlayer player, EnumHand hand)
    {
        if(player.getHeldItem(hand).getItem() instanceof ItemBucket &&!player.isCreative())
        {
            player.getHeldItem(hand).shrink(1);
            player.setHeldItem(hand, new ItemStack(Items.BUCKET));
        }
        ++this.waterValue;
        Logger.getGlobal().warning("AUMENTO DE AGUAA "+this.waterValue);
    }
    public void increaseLavaCount(EntityPlayer player, EnumHand hand)
    {
        if(player.getHeldItem(hand).getItem() instanceof ItemBucket&&!player.isCreative())
        {
            player.getHeldItem(hand).shrink(1);
            player.setHeldItem(hand, new ItemStack(Items.BUCKET));
        }
        ++this.lavaValue;
        Logger.getGlobal().warning("AUMENTO DE lavaaa " + this.lavaValue);
    }
    @Override
    public void readFromNBT(NBTTagCompound compound) {
        super.readFromNBT(compound);
        this.blockContents = NonNullList.<ItemStack>withSize(this.getSizeInventory(), ItemStack.EMPTY);

        if(!this.checkLootAndRead(compound)) ItemStackHelper.loadAllItems(compound, blockContents);
        if(compound.hasKey("CustomName", 8)) this.customName = compound.getString("CustomName");
    }
    @Override
    public NBTTagCompound writeToNBT(NBTTagCompound compound) {
        super.writeToNBT(compound);

        if(!this.checkLootAndRead(compound)) ItemStackHelper.saveAllItems(compound, blockContents);
        if(compound.hasKey("CustomName", 8)) compound.setString("CustomName", this.customName);
        return compound;

    }

    @Override
    public String getName()
    {
        return this.hasCustomName() ? this.customName : "container.fluid_container";
    }
    public void setCustomName(String displayName)
    {
        this.customName = displayName;      
    }
    @Override
    public int getSizeInventory() {
        return 16;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        for(ItemStack stack: this.blockContents)
        {
            if(!stack.isEmpty()) return false;
        }           
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public int getInventoryStackLimit()
    {
        return 128;
    }
    @Override
    public Container createContainer(InventoryPlayer playerInventory, EntityPlayer playerIn) 
    {
        return new ContainerFluidContainer(playerInventory, this, playerIn);
    }
    @Override
    public String getGuiID() 
    {
        return Reference.MOD_ID + ":fluid_container";
    }
    @Override
    protected NonNullList<ItemStack> getItems() 
    {
        return this.blockContents;
    }
    @Override
    public void openInventory(EntityPlayer player)
    {
        ++this.numPlayersUsing;
        this.world.addBlockEvent(this.pos, this.getBlockType(), 1, this.numPlayersUsing);
        this.world.notifyNeighborsOfStateChange(this.pos, this.getBlockType(), true);
    }
    @Override
    public void closeInventory(EntityPlayer player) 
    {
        --this.numPlayersUsing;
        this.world.addBlockEvent(this.pos, this.getBlockType(), 1, this.numPlayersUsing);
        this.world.notifyNeighborsOfStateChange(this.pos, this.getBlockType(), true);
    }
    @Override
    public void update() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Result was mind to be this:
while empty (both values equals 0)
http://prntscr.com/nnmvgx

while full (both values equasls 13)
http://prntscr.com/nnmw4c

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

## A lot of things I need to mention about your code...

1. You are running 1.12, this means you have access to [Capabilities](https://mcforge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/datastorage/capabilities/), which you should be using instead of all those integer values. In fact, there's already a capability for Fluid Handling; `CapabilityFluidHandler.FLUID_HANDLER_CAPABILITY`.
2. Don't extend `TileEntityLockableLoot`, it is almost certainly doing you no favors. The way vanilla Minecraft implements some things (like inventories) is inflexible and not a good way to do things when modding. `TileEntityLockableLoot` (and by extension, `IInventory`) is one of those things.
3. And now we get to why it doesn't work. You aren't telling the client about the amount of water and lava stored. You never synchronize this data to the client from the server.

You need to override [these three methods](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/1.12.1/src/main/java/com/draco18s/farming/entities/TileEntityTanner.java#L174-L189)<sup>1</sup> and make sure to [call these four](https://github.com/Draco18s/ReasonableRealism/blob/1.12.1/src/main/java/com/draco18s/farming/entities/TileEntityTanner.java#L95-L98) whenever the data changes.

1. <sub>Note that serializing the entire TE to NBT is not a great solution (as there is a lot of data passing over the network that will go unused), you should only serialize the necessary data, however this is a quick-and-dirty method that will work.</sub>